# Plotting circles in a Hadamard matrix pattern

Tags: matlab

I want to plot circles in Hadamard matrix pattern of order 8,16, and 32. So far, I have a code for plotting 2D arrays of circles.

```
%Plotting  an N by N arrays of circles
clc; clear;
n_circles = 8;                    % Define the number of circles to be plotted
R = 40;                      % Define the radius of the basic circle
Len=1024;
M=zeros(Len);               % Create the hole mask

% Get the indices of the points inside the basic circle
M0 = zeros(2*R+1);             % Initialize the basic mask
I = 1:(2*R+1);             % Define the x and y coordinates of the basic mask
x = (I - R)-1;
y = (R - I)+1;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);      % Create the mask
A = (X.^2 + Y.^2 <= R^2);   
[xx,yy]=ind2sub(size(M0),find(A == true));  

%plot
for ii=1:n_circles
    for jj=1:n_circles
      MidX=Len/2+(ii-n_circles/2-0.5)*(2*R);
      MidY=Len/2+(jj-n_circles/2-0.5)*(2*R);
%       [MidX MidY]
      M(sub2ind(size(M),MidX+xx-R-1,MidY+yy-R-1))=1;
    end
end
figure(1)
imshow(M)
```

I searched on how to plot a Hadamard matrix, and from the Mathworks documentation, [the hadamard matrix function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hadamard.html)

```
H = hadamard(n)
```

returns the Hadamard matrix of order n. How do I incorporate this in my original code so that the final result will generate an image of circles plotted in a Hadamard pattern, where the value of 1 indicates a circle while -1 is null (absence of circle)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in th begining

```
H = hadamard(n_circles);
```

and inside the loops change to:

```
M(sub2ind(size(M),MidX+xx-R-1,MidY+yy-R-1))=H(ii,jj);
```